# choice_value is missing django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

This is my `form`:

```
class SimpleSearchForm(forms.Form):
    options = [(obj.id, obj.name) for obj in Skill2.objects.filter(category="massage")]
    skills = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={"name": "select_0", "class": "full_search_checkbox"}),
        choices=options)
```

This is my `template.html`:

```
     {% for skill in simple_search_form.skills %}
         <input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="{{ skill.choice_value }}"
              {% if skill.choice_value in params.full_params %}checked{% endif %}/>

         <label> {{ skill.choice_label }}}</label>

     {% endfor %}
```

It works fine on `localhost` and I get this `html`:

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="skills" value="some_value">
 <label>some_text</label>
```

but on production server(I deploy to `pythonanywhere.com`)

I get the following html out put:

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="skills" value">
 <label>some_text</label>
```

As you can see value tag is missing, so what do I write to make it work?

Comment: try to restart wsgi

Comment: What is the value of `SimpleSearchForm.options` in production?

Comment: @vivek pradhan probably has the right answer.  The equivalent of restarting WSGI on PythonAnywhere is to hit the "Reload" button on the "Web" tab.